# count number of similar row values between multiple columns in excel and then find the percentage of it

Tags: excel

I am marking my students results and wish to find the way to calculate the percentage of correct answers based on the answers by the students in excel using excel functions.

example:

[image]

Here I have two rows with questions 1-12 as columns. row1: student answers, row2: correct answers.

Can anyone please help, thank you.

Expected output:

we have six similar values for row1 and row2, so it will be 6/12: 50%

Answer (score 0):

So a row to check if A1 = A2, use an if() to get a 1 or 0

Then sum to get the total, divide by 12 and * 100

So:

```
=IF(A1=A2,1,0)
```

and calculation at the end for percentage:

```
=sum(a2:l2)/12*100
```